# Fullstory events for API-created pages are not being captured

Tags: next.js, fullstory

Since some of the URLs I want to track contain query parameters, I am using the FullStory setVars API to send custom page data to FullStory (https://help.fullstory.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500004101581-FS-setVars-API-Sending-custom-page-data-to-FullStory?source=search). Although I can see the pages created through the API in the FullStory Pages UI, the events I create for these specific pages are not being tracked (they remain at 0 events). Additionally, I have observed an "Once set, page names cannot be changed" API error in the UI, which I don't fully understand.

I’m calling the API everytime the URL change (in order to be able to track click events to the specific pages I created). I’m calling it like below:

```js
// inside `const onChangeSelectedItem = (index: number)`
FullStory('setProperties', {
    type: 'page',
    properties: {
        pageName: dashboardIds[analyticsTabsEnum[market.toString()]][index].fullStoryName
    },
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: FullStory is correctly set up, as we have been using it for a while now and observing events for non-custom pages.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @lucasrotsenviridios,

We have replied to you via your support ticket with a more complete answer but we wanted to make sure anyone else who comes across this thread could find some of the advice we provided.

To clarify with Pages and query params:

- If only the query params change, but the page reloads, there would be a new "pageview". In this scenario you would be able to use the FS.setVars() and page names to distinguish these pages.
- If only the query params change, and the page does not reload, you could use the pagevar api with non-page-name  page vars to distinguish them.  Note that this can get misleading when looking for Heatmaps, and will not enable Journeys.

For example, if you call:

```
FS.setVars('page',{
  pageName: 'Same Page Name',
  custom_param_str: 'some value',
  custom_param_int: 34
});
```

you would use your properties to refine the filters in a search.

Hopefully this helps you adjust your API calls to get things moving in the right direction but if you need any further help, please respond to us via the support ticket and we will be here to assist :-)

Gemma